# エスケープシーケンスと、パスの形式

Tags: java

パスに使用するセパレータは、

1. WEB用
   `//`
2. WEB用(エスケープ付き)
   `////`
3. ファイルパス用
   `\\`
4. ファイルパス用(エスケープ付き) ※Windows用ファイルパス
   `\\\\`

をどういうときに、どれを使うべきか？
について質問（確認）です。

javaのプログラム上でパスを作成する場合は、
１と３

javaから、何かのAPIやミドルウェア等に処理依頼するときは、
１または３の場合と、
２または４の場合があるという理解で相違ないでしょうか？

※APIやミドルウェア等が、エスケープ付きの状態でinputを要求しているケースでは、
　実際のパスのセパレート文字の\、/を作りつつ、
　さらにエスケープシーケンスのための\、/を作る必要があるために2個分必要
　というケースがありうるため。

Comment: 「不正な形式」と出るのはURLの指定を`http:testSite`としているからではないですか？正しくは`http://testSite`のはずです。`/` スラッシュと `\\` バックスラッシュ(Windows等では円マークで表示される場合も)は別物です。

Comment: すみません、、例が悪かったです。。そこについては誤記です。

Comment: そこについては、と言うのはどこについてなのでしょうか? ご自身の質問は編集できるので誤記があれば編集をお願いします。また何を言いたいのかわからない部分が多いのですが、実際のコードを全く示されていないせいが一番大きいと思います。具体的なJavaのコード、JavaScriptのコードを関連箇所に明示していただけませんか。

Comment: @user29668 さん、追記部分についてですが、どの処理が為されたあとでの文字列なのか？に応じて文字列中のエスケープシーケンスが処理されるかされないかが変わってしまうので、単に文字列というだけでは判断ができません。たとえば文字列リテラルとして `"a\\b"` と書くと `a\b` という文字列として扱われますが、後者のバックスラッシュはバックスラッシュそのものです。このような事情から質問者さんの抱えていらっしゃる問題を把握しづらいので、ソースコード断片を出せそうであれば可能な範囲で出して頂けるとありがたいです <(_ _)> （何らかの事情により不可能なのであればそう言って頂けると嬉しいです）

Comment: @user29668 また別件として、通常エスケープシーケンスのために使うのはバックスラッシュのみです。`"//"` は単に `//` として扱われます。そのあたりにも誤解の要因がありそうだなと思っています。いかがでしょうか。

Comment: XMLHttpRequestを呼んでいるJavaScriptのパラメータ渡しに誤りがあり、確認していたurlにリクエストができていないことが原因でした。 アプリケーションログには意図するurlが出ていたのですが、ログ出力が関数の外だったため、誤認してしまったことが原因です。。 申し訳ありません。 また、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

後半について:

> エスケープシーケンスを考慮した文字

まず第一に、エスケープシーケンスという語を誤解しています。

エスケープシーケンスというのは "バックスラッシュ+文字" という2文字で特別な意味を持たせた文字のことです。今回登場しているものとしては `'\\'` が該当します(それ以外については末尾参考リンクを参照)。

繰り返しになりますが、エスケープシーケンスは「(特殊な書式の)文字」です。
｢(特殊な書式の)文字を考慮した文字｣というのは意味が通じません。

したがって、

> (前略)と捉えていますが、間違っているでしょうか？

に対する回答としては、そもそも質問文として成立していません、となります。

エスケープシーケンスとかその辺の単語の意味は置いておいて、
バックスラッシュを2つ重ねれば `\` が出力される、それを確認するには実際に出力してみる、

```
System.out.println('\\');
System.out.println("\\\\");
```

で良いと思うのですがいかがでしょう。

前半の質問については、他の方がコメントされているとおり現在の文章では状況が正しく把握できないので回答不能です。
(スラッシュとバックスラッシュは別物なので、一方が通って他方が通らないこと自体は取り立てて不思議なことではないと思いますが。)

参考:

- [The Java™ Tutorials - Characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: > cublicさん、OOperさん
> そこについては、と言うのはどこについてなのでしょうか?
http:testSiteとしていたところは
http://testSite が正です。

＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊

>　nekketsuuuさん
URL、Javaの文字列リテラル、OSごとのパス
については、

文面上の以下の部分の、

ファイルシステム用のパス
「¥」と、
web用のパス
｢/｣があると思います。

と思っています。

エスケープの仕方は、｢理解確認｣のところで書いた内容の認識です。

Comment: >　nekketsuuuさん
"//" は単に // として扱われます。

自分もその認識です。

自分はダブルコートでくくっていないため、
単に javaの世界のstringの変数上で// としていたものが
httpリクエストされるとき、urlパラメータとしては/として使われていると捉えています。

Comment: >　yukihaneさん
>　バックスラッシュを2つ重ねれば \ が出力される、それを確認するには実際に出力してみる
System.out.println('\\');
System.out.println("\\\\");

｢バックスラッシュを2つ重ねれば \ が出力される｣という認識は自分も同じです。

Comment: > greenteaさん
> Windows上の話でしようか?
前提が足りずすみません、windowsです

Answer (score 1):

他の方のコメントや回答に有るように、色々と混同したり、勘違いしているように見受けられますので、URL、Javaの文字列リテラル、OSごとのパスの区切り文字など、それぞれの仕様を把握されると全体的に理解できるのかなと感じました。

その上で、回答がついてないところだけ 書きますと

ブラウザの場合は、手元の環境で試したところ、HTTPサーバーのアクセスログを見ても区切り文字は常に `/` なので、ブラウザが `\` を `/` に置き換えて、サーバーにリクエストしていると思います。

エラーメッセージの区切り文字が `\` に置換されて表示されたというのは、ご質問の `http:testSite/hogehoge/test.html` の場合は、先頭にスキーム（`scheme://`形式) がありませんので、URLの構文になっておらず、そもそもが URLとは認識されてないので、ローカルファイルパスと解釈された為ではないか、と思います。このへんは推測なので違うかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

まず、確認ですが、Windows上の話でしようか?
Unix(Linux)上でのバス区切り文字は常に **/** です。**\** は、常にエスケープ文字扱いです。 (ここの書込みも同様?)

これが、Windows世界だと、ディレクトリ区切り文字も、**\** で　エスケープ文字と同じになります。 ( / は引数に使われた)

URLの指定(形式)は、Unixから、来ていますので、ディレクトリ区切りは */* で、/ から始まるとローカルルートからのパス、// はスーパールートで外部となります。 Windowsでは、これがそのまま、**\** に置き換えられますが、URLに指定する場合、/ となります。

なお、

> ｢¥｣区切りの方のパスをコピペして、
>   改めてブラウザに張り付けてリクエストすると、

Windows上のブラウザは大抵、\ 区切りを / とみなします。 (Linux上は、知らない)

Comment: 「Windows上のブラウザは大抵、\ 区切りを / とみなします。」になるほどでした。バグだと思ってたら動いて、不思議に思っていました。

また、
/ から始まるとローカルルートからのパス、
// はスーパールートで外部
ということを知らず、これもなるほどでした。

すごく助かりました！有難うございます。